# C# invoke base constructor with parameters and parameterless constructor of current class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor, virtual

```
public class A
{
    public A() { Console.WriteLine("A parameterless"); }
    public A(int a) : this() { Console.WriteLine("A with a"); }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B() { Console.WriteLine("B paramterless"); }
    public B(int b) : base(b) { Console.WriteLine("B with b"); }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new B(3);
    }
}
```

Gives:
A parameterless
A with a
B with b

What can I do to invoke "B parameterless" as well?
So, I'd need something along the lines of:

```
public B(int b) : base(b), this() { ... }
```

Or, a virtual constructor, so that when the base class invokes `this()`, it redirects to child's parameterless constructor.

Comment: You can't. You get to pick *one* other constructor to chain to. If the question was less *abstract* and we knew what you were actually doing (beyond printing debugging information to the Console) we may have *concrete* suggestions for how better to approach the problem.

Comment: You can't, you can only create a direct chain through the constructors, not to a constructor then back and to a different constructor. As such, you can create a chain from B(int) to B(), and then to either A() or A(int). If you want to go B(int)->B()->A(int) you have lost that int on the way as no code in B(int) has executed yet. Virtual constructors are not part of the C# language. You should explain more about which problem you're trying to solve as there may be other ways to deal with it.

Comment: ... yet there is a workaround: You can call a private method inside both `B()` and `B(int b)`

Comment: @Fildor That is true, but if you're trying to assign values to readonly fields that is not possible in those methods. Again, we need more information about the underlying problem in order to suggest good solutions.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, that's a drawback. And that's the point where Damien's comment kicks in _"If the question was less abstract and we knew what you were actually doing [...] we may have concrete suggestions for how better to approach the problem"_

Comment: Just an idea (untested) : What about ditching `B()` and having `B(int? b = null)` ? https://dotnetfiddle.net/sYtKRf

Comment: I'm quite satisfied with Damien's answer "You can't." (even if I'm not satisfied with that fact). The problem is as Lasse described, assigning a value to a readonly field that needs a reference to `this`. I know how to proceed from here. If someone wants to post an answer saying "You can't", I'll accept it :D

Comment: @Fildor Havin a default parameter would require major changes in the framework which would make everything uglier than one non-readonly field.

Comment: @MackThax OK. I just thought the idea was worth sharing. BTW: What will be the value of `a` in `A` after calling `A()` ?

Comment: @Fildor If you are refering to the underlying field parameter `a` is being assigned to, it is set by reflection. I don't want to go into specifics because this is a part of a serialization system in our code I could write pages about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it with constructor chaining. But I dont see any problem with this:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A parameterless");
    }
    public A(int a) : this()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A with a");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        ThingsIWant();
    }
    public B(int b) : base(b)
    {
        ThingsIWant();
        Console.WriteLine("B with b");
    }

    protected void ThingsIWant()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B paramterless");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new B(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I dont see any problem with this"_ - Try to assign values to readonly fields in `ThingsIWant` ...

Comment: @Fildor that's exactly what I want. "You can't", however, is the answer to this question.

Comment: Would having a readonly _Property_ be an option? `private string field; //set in ThingsIWant` and then `public string Field { get => field; }` ?

Comment: @Fildor The field is private, anyway. This is not a major problem, I was just trying to protect myself from accidentally changing it. Just seemed cleaner if it was readonly.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to extend on the “can’t” answers and add “shouldn’t”. The use case for multiple constructor overloads is receive different inputs relevant to the construction of the object, usually having the constructor that receives less information provide appropriate defaults for values supplied to the other constructor. From a maintainability perspective, you would typically have the overload containing the most detailed arguments be the only place where the real construction logic exists and have the other constructors call that one.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this leads to the exact problem, but in reverse. Now parameterless constructors need to invoke `this(x)` with some default parameters, and I'd have to repeat that for each class, which is code duplication. Otherwise, I'd need to invoke `base()` which would then fail to invoke child's constructor with parameters.

Comment: @MackThax the child class parameterless constructor would invoke its own more detailed constructor, which in turn would ensure the desired base class constructor. The base isn’t calling constructors of the child.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to assign values to readonly fields in ThingsIWant

This is a language/compiler limitation: the compiler allows you to change a readonly field only **physically** inside a constructor and not in a method called during the costruction of the object.

An old [msdn document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7(VS.80).aspx) states:

> "When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class."